# Excluding default asset folders from Asset Path - Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I hope I've a good understanding about how to implement Rails asset pipeline in all the environments.

From my understanding, I know that we can add a custom folder to the asset path, But can we remove the folders from deafult paths i.e., `'app/assets/', 'vendor/assets', 'lib/assets'` from asset path? Is there any provision for the same?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: I'm not sure what this is asking - you want to remove the ability to serve assets from `app/assets`? why?

Comment: Say, there is a situation in production mode where I do not require the files inside 'vendor/assets' to be precompiled. So, what should I do?

Comment: Just don't require them in your application.css (or other manifest files) then.

Comment: @sevenseacat: Can you just tell me how we can do that since 'vendor/assets' comes under default asset paths?

Comment: Wherever you're requiring a file from the vendor folder; don't require it.

Comment: @sevenseacat: I'm not requiring any 'vendor/assets' folder. But it is allocated to Rails default asset paths. That is why I'm asking how we could remove it?

Comment: You're misunderstanding how the asset pipeline works - just because its in the path list, doesn't mean files in it will automatically get precompiled. (except images I believe)

Comment: @sevenseacat: Could you please just explain by giving an answer for this question.?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redefine where the assets are served from by default  you can change prefix:

> config.assets.prefix

For instance, if you want to change it from  /assets to liability, you do:config.assets.prefi= "/liability"

Comment: No, this is to change the location for precompiled assets.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer, ref: [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Pipeline assets can be placed inside an application in one of three locations: **app/assets**, **lib/assets** or **vendor/assets**.

- app/assets is for assets that are owned by the application, such as custom images, JavaScript files or stylesheets.
- lib/assets is for your own libraries' code that doesn't really fit into the scope of the application or those libraries which are shared across applications.
- vendor/assets is for assets that are owned by outside entities, such as code for JavaScript plugins and CSS frameworks.

> If you are upgrading from Rails 3, please take into account that
>   assets under lib/assets or vendor/assets are available for inclusion
>   via the application manifests but no longer part of the precompile
>   array. See Precompiling Assets for guidance.

So, no worries. we can manage it through Manifest file.